# Threads in brass floor lamp post have been stripped. No longer twists and stays in place. How can I fix the threads?

Tags: repair

I have a floor lamp that comes in sections that you twist to screw together. the threads on one section have become stripped and the sections no longer stay together. Is there a way I can fix these threads at home instead of throwing the whole lamp out?

Comment: Do you need to be able to disassemble the threaded sections later?

Comment: JB weld will do it but it will no longer be able to dissamble (JB weld is a metal filled epoxy )  it is silver gray in color so if the threads are exposed it may not look as nice but it can handle heat and is very strong. most hardware stores and auto part stores carry it.

Comment: Self-tapping screws one size larger?

Answer (score 4):

If there are any remnants of the stripped threads that you can feel, you might try wrapping some plumber's teflon tape, or other vinyl tape around them several times, and see if they will screw tight with the tape on.  You might need only one wrap, if the tape is thick.

Answer (score 4):

If I am reading this right, it isn't a screw that's stripped, it's the main tubular shaft of the floor lamp that screws together.  Using epoxy might be strong enough but you might need electrical continuity in that shaft for grounding purposes.

Depending on how mangled the threads are, you may be able to clean them up with a small sharp file.  Once in a while that works.

You could re-tap the threads, or cut off half an inch and re-tap the tubing, but you have to have the right size tap, and that's not something you probably have laying around the house.  A plumber might, a machine shop would.

Comment: I doubt either has the appropriate tap, I'd assume tiny threads like that are lathe cut and the couplings are cast and then machined. Hiring this out or purchasing any equipment will cost more than a nice new lamp.

Answer (score 1):

OMG... I fully get how trivial thus is, but FINALLY my favorite floor lamp is straight. I bought the lamp almost 20 yrs ago. The house it was bought for has been GONE over a decade. The lamp is a stupid relic, but it's my fav. So withbthat said, one of the threaded sections was stripped out and wouldn't support top. Hubby had put 2 support brackets, but still was "off." After I'd gotten tired of looking at the jacked up lamp, it got moved aside. I grabbed the teflon tape. Tried that, but not "quite" enough. Found electrical tape and DONE! I haven't seen it like this in YEARS! Now to add the antlers to jazz it up for the cabin.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the screws, fill the holes with jb weld, durhams putty, or a similar material, then when is dry, drill out smaller holes in the filler material and use screws to fit those holes.  Or skip that and just use screws a tiiiiiny bit bigger than the stripped holes so they still dig in.